# osx homebrew permission issues

Tags: macos, package-management, homebrew

I am having a lot of permission issue on my OSX 10.13.4 machine. Homebrew seems to be unable to correctly finish the package installation correctly.

Here is the following exemple for `npm` but I have the same issue with `node`. both seem to be installed but not linked to my environment if I understand well. I have tried all I could find but I am running dry of ideas. I also tried uninstalling/reinstalling Homebrew

`brew install npm` I get a symlink error:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
npm -v gives env: node: No such file or directory
```

`brew link node` and `brew postinstall node` give the same error

`brew doctor` gives me another bunch of warnings:

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
node

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
```

`brew prune` gives Error: `Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/JSONStream`

Comment: you have to reinstall the brew! 
try
 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Comment: or try update brew

Comment: @Rizwanatta I tried uninstalling / reinstalling Homebrew but that did not fix the issue